# How to schedule multiple local notification in ios 10 Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

Actually I done local notification scheduling but it only schedule one notification.I have array of Reminder Model,each model object contain title,notes,taskID,date such a different information.so using for loop i am setting notification content,trigger,identifier and making request but notification not appear. Following is my code
.............................................................................

```
func setNotification(tasks:[RemiderModel]){    

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: tasks.count, by: 1)
    {

        self.scheduleLocal(task: tasks[i])

    }
}

func scheduleLocal(task:RemiderModel)
{

    //let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    //center.delegate = self

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = task.mTitle
    //content.subtitle = "Rahul"//array[i]["title"]!
    content.body = task.mNotes//array[i]["note"]!
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = 1
    let triggerTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: task.reminder)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerTime, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: task.taskID, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {error in
        if error != nil
        {
            print(error!)
        }

    })

  override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
```

Comment: are you sure that title is not nil?

Comment: Not important but not so sure why you're using `stride`...can't you just use a simple for-loop?

Comment: Are your `taskID`s all the same or each of them are different?

Comment: Yes, taskID is different for each

Comment: Thanks ,sorry but i actually forgot to assign taskID to model from array

Comment: So likely that's the issue. Because when they are the same...it means that you're **updating** (not creating a new notification) and you'r only seeing the last notification that comes with that ID...

Comment: How to add location base  notification like this .I have array of location(lat,long) and want to set location for reminder.I searched on google but didn't found any proper information so, if anyone know about this then please help me.(i want step by step guideline)